# How to normalize time series data in R?

Tags: r

I have the matrix below. How do I divide each row with its mean?

```
 TAXA   1992    1993    1994     1995   
 Aba    1        0      0.01     0  
 Abr    2      0.084    0.1      3  
 Amp    7         6     4        2
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you want either of these -

For a data frame:

```
cbind(df[1], df[-1] / rowMeans(df[-1]))
#   TAXA    X1992      X1993      X1994     X1995
# 1  Aba 3.960396 0.00000000 0.03960396 0.0000000
# 2  Abr 1.543210 0.06481481 0.07716049 2.3148148
# 3  Amp 1.473684 1.26315789 0.84210526 0.4210526
```

For a matrix:

```
m / rowMeans(m)
#         1992       1993       1994      1995
# Aba 3.960396 0.00000000 0.03960396 0.0000000
# Abr 1.543210 0.06481481 0.07716049 2.3148148
# Amp 1.473684 1.26315789 0.84210526 0.4210526
```

This finds the mean of each row then divides each row by its corresponding mean.  The first assumes the first column in your example is actually a column, while the second assumes it is row names in a matrix.

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(TAXA = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Aba", "Abr", 
"Amp"), class = "factor"), X1992 = c(1L, 2L, 7L), X1993 = c(0, 
0.084, 6), X1994 = c(0.01, 0.1, 4), X1995 = c(0L, 3L, 2L)), .Names = c("TAXA", 
"X1992", "X1993", "X1994", "X1995"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

m <- structure(c(1, 2, 7, 0, 0.084, 6, 0.01, 0.1, 4, 0, 3, 2), .Dim = 3:4, .Dimnames = list(
    c("Aba", "Abr", "Amp"), c("1992", "1993", "1994", "1995"
    )))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the ['tidy data'](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) approach (I copied the data from question to clipboard):

```
t <- read.table("clipboard", sep=" ", header=T)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
t %>% 
  gather(year, value, -TAXA) %>% 
  group_by(TAXA) %>% 
  mutate(value=value / mean(value)) %>% 
  spread(year, value)
```

You get:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 5]

  TAXA    X1992      X1993      X1994     X1995
1  Aba 3.960396 0.00000000 0.03960396 0.0000000
2  Abr 1.543210 0.06481481 0.07716049 2.3148148
3  Amp 1.473684 1.26315789 0.84210526 0.4210526
```

It gathers the values from many columns into one. (They're getting the same treatment, they should be in one column.) Then it calculates the mean for each `TAXA` separately, and reformats the data back into the wide format.